# Inverting the curve of a logarithmic scale in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a map that plots cities, where the radius of the city dot is adjusted by population.  We want only the larger cities to be noticeably larger at a glance.  I've tried using a logarithmic scale, but that's giving me the reverse where the radius scales up quickly.

I've tried using log.invert(), but anything but the smallest numbers give a result of infinity.

As a note I don't really know how logarithmic or other scales work mathematically.  I've only ever applied them to my visualizations.

Simplification of my code:
    var radiusScale = d3.scale.log().domain([1,8000000]).range([1,3])

EDIT:
What I've ended up needing to do was use d3.scale.sqrt() then adjusting the domain to exclude the outlier large cites, which brought the high end of the domain down to 800,000 from 8,000,000.  This is giving us the effect of cities slowly scaling up, with an acceleration of the scale; where logarithmic was the reverse of quickly scaling with deceleration.

Comment: What's the minimum and maximum radii you want, and what are the corresponding minimum and maximum city populations?

Comment: The radius we're currently looking at is a range from 1 - 3.  The city populations run from 1 (there are a few actually with population: 1) to a little over 8 million (NYC).

Comment: For such a small range of radii, why not just keep it simple and set some arbitrary sizes like `radius = population <=1000000 ? 1 : (population <= 5000000 ? 2 : 3);`